# cocoa detect object in mouse clicked

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, object, nsimage, nsevent

I created a custom object (NSImageView) to display images and I use addSubview: self.view to add 
I want to determine if the mouse click in it. 
How do I do?

Thank you.

```
NSImage *Image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"oneimage.jpg"];
NSImageView *ImageView = [[NSImageView alloc] init];
[ImageView setImage:Image];
[self.window addSubview:ImageView];
[ImageView_IconToAdd setAcceptsTouchEvents:YES];
[ImageView_IconToAdd setWantsRestingTouches:YES];


-(void)mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    id clickedObject = [self hitTest:[theEvent locationInWindow]];
    if ([clickedObject isKindOfClass:[NSImageView class]]) {
        NSLog(@"Clicked an ImageView");
    } else if ([clickedObject isKindOfClass:[NSView class]]) {
        NSLog(@"Clicked a WebView");
    }
}
```

But error:

`No visible @interface for 'WindowImage' declares the selector 'hitTest:'`

And can't get Object!

Comment: What is the class of `WindowImage` then?

Comment: Non error in WindowImage